# What is the difference between "ArrayList<String> = new ArrayList<>()" and "ArrayList<String> = new ArrayList<String>()"?

Tags: java

just like the title said, in Java, is there any difference between the two statements?

Usually I can see the two statements both. So I suppose there may be no difference. But could you help to confirm and explain why they are identical?

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); 
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
```

Thanks!

Comment: they are identical just two ways of writing.

Comment: Hi, all, I want to thank you all so much for your answers!! Just mark the first one as acceptable answer, but I think all your answers are clear and correct identically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are identical. `new ArrayList<String>();` was required prior to JDK 7. In JDK 7 they introduced the 'diamond operator', where the type is inferred.

So, if you are using JDK 7+ you can simply use `new Arraylist<>()`

You can see this in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html) under Class Instance Creation Expressions, or search for 'Diamond Operator'

Answer (score 0):

In java 7 and later there is no difference. The latter is considered more concise.
 The so called diamond operator `<>` is helping here for the type to be inferred.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Diamond Operator.

The Diamond Operator reduces some of Java's verbosity surrounding generics by having the compiler infer parameter types for constructors of generic classes.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html